# MultiIndex Pandas does not group first index level

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I am trying to create a Pandas Dataframe with two levels of index in the rows.

```
info = pd.DataFrame([['A', 1, 3],
                   ['A', 2, 4],
                   ['A', 3, 6],
                   ['B', 1, 9],
                   ['B', 2, 10],
                   ['B', 4, 6]], columns=pd.Index(['C', 'D', 'V'])    
info_new = info.set_index(['C', 'D'], drop=False)
```

EDIT: I want the following output:

```
     V
C  D
A  1 3
   2 4
   3 6
B  1 9
   2 10
   4 6
```

According to every instruction I found, this should work.
I am still getting

```
     V
C  D
A  1 3
A  2 4
A  3 6
B  1 9
B  2 10
B  4 6
```

So apparently, the multiindex does not work here.

I checked each column with non-unique values with `.is_unique`, the answer is False.
I checked the columns with unique values, the answer is True.
I also tried to assign a dtype=str, this didn't change anything.

Comment: What do you want the output to be?

Comment: Sorry this works for me according to my understanding, can you post what you're seeing which you think is an error

Comment: Try printing `info_new.index`. You should get `MultiIndex(...)`

Comment: What does `info_new.index.is_lexsorted()` return? If lexsorted it should appear as you expect.

Comment: Output added. It says that it is a multiindex, but it doesn't behave like one.

Comment: @AndrewL: lexsorted is False.

Comment: What is your pandas version as this works in latest pandas

Comment: `info_new.sort_index(inplace=True)` should fix

Comment: Exactly, figured that out after your question! Thanks a lot, @AndrewL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the `info_new.index.is_lexsorted()` comment.

I solved it by specifying dtype=str in the .csv import and then:

```
info_new.sortlevel(inplace=True)
```

Comment: In the current version of pandas, it's `info_new.sort_index(inplace=True)`